# Generation of a random vector on an affine hyperplane

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, random-generation

I would like to design a proposal of the form:

$$
p(t=(t_i)|\hat{t}=(\hat{t}_i))
$$

where $t$ (and $\hat{t}$) lies in an affine hyperplane $T \subset R^n$:

$$
t \in T  \Leftrightarrow
\sum_i t_i=1
$$

Ideally I would like to approach something like:
$$
(t_i)| (\hat{t}_i) \sim \mathcal{N}((\hat{t}_i),\sigma^2 I)
$$
with the constraint that $\sum_i t_i=1$ (or anything in a similar flavor).

An intuitive strategy could result in the following algorithm:

1) sample individually $\tilde{t}_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\hat{t_i},\sigma)$

2) then renormalise $t_i = \frac{\tilde{t}_i}{\sum_j \tilde{t}_j}$

but it seems to me a bit difficult to characterise the resulting proposal (and particularly to compute $\frac{p(t=(t_i)|\hat{t}=(\hat{t}_i))}{p(\hat{t}=(\hat{t}_i))|t=(t_i))}$ as I am applying it within a metropolis hasting algorithm).

Is anybody has an alternative proposal or some idea on how to deal with $\frac{p(t=(t_i)|\hat{t}=(\hat{t}_i))}{p(\hat{t}=(\hat{t}_i))|t=(t_i))}$ ?

Note: I deal with large $n$ ($T \subset R^n$) and thus need a quite efficient strategy.

Comment: The verbose notation gets in the way of the question itself.  (Why on earth do you need *two* subscripts $i$ almost everywhere?) Are you just asking how to generate iid Normal samples efficiently on an affine subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the subscripts: maybe a bad habit... If generating normal samples on an affine subset as a sense (I was a bit confused about that, which in part explains my over-extensive question); I am indeed just asking how to do it (and thanks for having clarified it).

Comment: The easiest way consists in generating a standard multivariate normal distribution of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then to transform the sample by applying the projection matrix onto the subspace, and finally to add the "intercept".

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks. So the projection matrix $P$ writes in homogeneous coordinates :
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
2/3& -1/3 & -1/3 & 1/3\\
-1/3& 2/3 & -1/3 & 1/3\\
-1/3& -1/3 & 2/3 & 1/3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
So $t=P \tilde{t}$ with $\tilde{t} \sim N(\hat{t},\sigma^2 I)$. Is that right ? I am not confortable with the meaning of underlying pdf $p(t | \hat{t})$. Can you help me to understand it?

Comment: In, the previous comment I assumed a 3D case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are two general approaches**: the *implicit* and the *parametric*.   Stéphane Laurent describes the **implicit method** in a comment: generate a $N(\mu, \sigma^2\mathbb{I}_n)$ variate in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and project that *orthogonally* onto the affine subset.  This works due to the spherical symmetry of the distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  A little computation is needed to choose $\mu$ correctly.

The implicit approach will be inefficient when $n$ is much larger than the dimension of the affine subspace.  It also does not readily generalize to other multivariate normal distributions without a bit of work--and that work will be more extensive than the parametric method.

The **parametric method** chooses an origin $O$ (intended to be the mean) and orthonormal basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_d)$ for the affine subset $\mathbb{A}^d\in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Generate a $N(0, \sigma^2\mathbb{I}_d)$ variate $y = (y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_d)$ and form

$$Y = y_1 e_1 + y_2 e_2 + \cdots + y_d e_d + O.$$

It should be obvious that this works and produces the desired result.  Moreover, any desired covariance structure can be induced on this distribution by changing $\sigma^2\mathbb{I}_d$ to an arbitrary positive-definite symmetric matrix $\Sigma$; nothing else changes.  Conceptually, all we have done is taken a $d$-dimensional multivariate normal distribution and moved it into $n$ dimensions via rotation and translation.

(The parametric method, then, easily generalizes to non-spherical and non-normal distributions whereas the implicit method does not, because the implicit method involves irrelevant random components distributed within the remaining $n-d$ dimensions that can make it difficult or impossible to achieve the desired distribution on $\mathbb{A}^d$.)

If (*) $\mathbb{A}^d$ is presented to you as the span of a set of vectors (and an origin), then the [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) directly produces the $(e_i)$.  Otherwise, if $\mathbb{A}^d$ is given as the solution of a set of linear equations (and an origin), then various well-known, widely-implemented algorithms will find a set of vectors spanning the [kernel (null space)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29#Null_space_of_a_linear_map) of those equations, putting us into the first situation (*).

Comment: Thanks ! Can you just explain "A little computation is needed to choose $\mu$ correctly" ?

Comment: Yes: when you project onto the affine subspace, $\mu$ (a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ gets projected somewhere. *You need it to get projected to the mean of the distribution you desire on that subspace.*  If $\mathbb{P}$ is the orthogonal projection matrix and $\mu_d$ (in $\mathbb{A}^d$) is the intended mean, then you must find some value of $\mu$ for which $\mathbb{P}\mu = \mu_d$.

Comment: "The parametric method chooses an origin O (intended to be the mean)". I would said that the mean is more related to the mean of the gaussian from which are drawn the $(y_i)$ and that the value of O is more concerned by the equation of the hyperplane. Am I right ? (maybe it is just a question of vocabulary...)

Comment: In either method you have to specify a *mean* for the distribution on  $\mathbb{A}^d$ as well as the covariance structure there.  When $\mathbb{A}^d$ is given implicitly as a set of solutions of linear equations, it inherits no distinguished origin.  Similarly, when it is parameterized as the span of a basis plus some offset, it still has no distinguished origin. No matter what, *you* need to stipulate where in $\mathbb{A}^d$ the mean of your distribution is located.

Comment: For the 1st method, why couldn't one generate a centered Gaussian and then adding $\mu_d$ after projection ?

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent Yes, that's probably the simplest way to do it.  It works provided $\mu=0$ initially and insisting that the projection be orthogonal.